# Can't install new software in Eclipse Mars M1

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-mars

I'm trying to install new software, API Tools Execution Environment Description, in Eclipse Mars M1 on Windows 7.

I've added the Update site and it shows the software I need in the list, but there is no way to continue after selecting it.  Both the `Next` and `Finish` buttons remain disabled.

Any ideas?

See screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Possibly you need to be running the current Milestone 3 version of Mars

Comment: Weird.  I thought that I was downloading the latest one.  I expected Eclipse to allow to update from within the IDE as well.  I will try to download M3 and test.  Thanks.

Comment: These are pre-release Milestone builds, the normal update process does not apply.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I installed Luna instead.